# Base class 'class A' should be explicitly initialized in the copy constructor

Tags: c++, qt

I confused by compiler warning. I used MinGW 5.3.0 32bit and i try to compile this code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>    

class A : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        A(QObject* parent = 0){ Q_UNUSED(parent);}
        ~A() {qDebug()<<"~A()";}

        virtual void func(){}
    private:

    };

    class B : public A
    {
        Q_OBJECT

        public:
            B(){}
            B (const B & object) {/*do somthing*/}
            ~B(){}

            void func(){/*do somthing*/}
    private:

    };

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

        return a.exec();
    }
```

My compiler tell me:

In copy constructor 'B::B(const B&)':
WARNING: base class 'class A' should be explicitly initialized in the copy constructor [-Wextra]
         B (const B & object) {/*do somthing*/}
         ^

Whats wrong?

Comment: Unrelated: When you have virtual methods in a base class, make sure the base class destructor is virtual as well.

Comment: Just init it explicitly. `B(const B& o):A(o){ }.  The code works as posted on g++.

Comment: Something to note, your class `A` is a subclass of `QObject` and [`QObject` cannot be copied](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor-or-assignment-operator). What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 7):

For a hand-rolled copy constructor (i.e. your `B::B(const B &)`) it is unusual (although not technically illegal in standard C++) in practice to rely on the default constructor of `A` being invoked - which is what will happen if you implement the copy constructor of `B` without explicitly initialising the `A` in the initialiser list of `B` constructor.

Your compiler is configured to warn about such things.   That is a quality-of-implementation concern for compilers (they are not required to issue warnings in cases like this).   But, practically, your compile vendor is doing you a favour.

Your copy constructor of `B`

```
B (const B & object) {/*do somthing*/}
```

is actually equivalent to

```
B (const B & object) : A() {/*do somthing*/}
```

which, as I said above, is unusual to explicitly do in practice - it is rarely a desirable behaviour.

The way to shut your compiler up, so it doesn't issue this warning, is to explicitly construct `A` in the initialiser list of `B`s constructor.   You could do it like the above using the default constructor of `A` (which, theoretically, may or may not stop the compiler complaining), but the more usual technique is something akin to

```
B (const B & object) : A(object) {/*do somthing*/}
```

Bear in mind that the copy constructor of `A` will be invoked before the body of `B` constructors (i.e. base classes are constructed first).

Even better, you would be better off not defining a copy constructor at all, if possible.   In that case (assuming something doesn't prevent it from doing so, such as a `private` copy constructor of a base class) the compiler will automatically generate a copy constructor for `B` that initialises all its base classes using their copy constructors (recursively) and all its data members.

Comment: simple clear answers make sense!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your class B inherits from A that itself inherits from QObject class which is not designed to be copyable.

Therefore you cannot call the QObject copy constructor in your class A copy constructor provided you have implemented one.

You can still call the default constructor from A in B copy ctor `B (const B & object) : A()` or even `B (const B & object) : A(object)` but it will never construct an exact copy of your object.

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/object.html#identity-vs-value for more detailed explanation of Qt's choice.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing copy constructor for class B but your parent, class A is default constructed. I (and presumably - compiler as well) would expect B's copy constructor to also copy-construct its parent. And given a fact that you have destructor and a virtual function in A you should seriously consider either creating copy constructor for A or disabling it altogether.

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted. The answer is more or less correct, though not as good as that of Peter.

Comment: Sorry if it i. Thanks for your answer. He is useful for me.